# How can i get last event from event stream using siddhi

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have two event stream: source and dest.

Source:

```
{
"name":"src.testevent",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "source test event stream",
"metaData":[{"name":"id","type":"INT"}], 
"correlationData":[],   
"payloadData":[]
}
```

Destination:

```
{
"name":"sink.testevent",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "sink test event stream",
"metaData":[{"name":"id","type":"int"}], 
"correlationData":[],   
"payloadData":[{"name":"Severity","type":"INT"}]
}
```

Execution plan is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<executionPlan name="testexecplan"
 statistics="disable" trace="enable"
 xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventprocessor">

  <description>Execution plan for testing</description>
  <siddhiConfiguration>
    <property name="siddhi.enable.distributed.processing">false</property>
    <property name="siddhi.persistence.snapshot.time.interval.minutes">0</property>
  </siddhiConfiguration>
  <importedStreams>
    <stream as="srcstream" name="src.testevent" version="0.0.1"/>
  </importedStreams>
  <queryExpressions><![CDATA[

// Create temporary stream
define stream tmpstream (id int, Severity int);

// Create some events at tmpstream
from srcstream as a
select a.meta_id as id, 0 as Severity
insert into tmpstream;

from srcstream as a
select a.meta_id as id, 1 as Severity
insert into tmpstream;

from srcstream as a
select a.meta_id as id, 2 as Severity
insert into tmpstream;

// Move last event from temporary stream to sink stream
from tmpstream#window.Length(1) as a
select a.id as meta_id, a.Severity
insert into sinkstream;

]]></queryExpressions>
  <exportedStreams>
    <stream name="sink.testevent" valueOf="sinkstream" version="0.0.1"/>
  </exportedStreams>
</executionPlan>
```

I need to pass the **last** event from tmpstream to sinkstream. I thought I need to use window with length(1). When i try event simulator (with attribute 112233) i received a reply with three events in sink event stream:

```
12:22:29,290 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-29]  INFO TenantId=-1234 : Event Processor : testexecplan,src.testevent:0.0.1 (srcstream), before processing 
[112233]
12:22:29,297 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-29]  INFO TenantId=-1234 : Event Processor : testexecplan,sink.testevent:0.0.1 (sinkstream), after processing 
[Event{streamId='sinkstream', timeStamp=1399537349292, data=[112233, 2], type=new}]
12:22:29,297 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-29]  INFO TenantId=-1234 : Event Processor : testexecplan,sink.testevent:0.0.1 (sinkstream), after processing 
[Event{streamId='sinkstream', timeStamp=1399537349292, data=[112233, 1], type=new}]
12:22:29,297 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-29]  INFO TenantId=-1234 : Event Processor : testexecplan,sink.testevent:0.0.1 (sinkstream), after processing 
[Event{streamId='sinkstream', timeStamp=1399537349292, data=[112233, 0], type=new}]
```

I.e. three events after processing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Length windows would simply keep the most recent number of events specified and expire the older ones. In your case, since the window size is 1, it would keep the last event and expire others.

I think what you are looking for is output rate limiting [1] which can output the last event for a window based on time or length. Something like the query below instead of your last query might work for you.

```
from tmpstream 
select id, Severity 
output last every 3 events
insert into sinkstream;
```

Comment: If less than three events in tmp eventstream (for example: from srcstream[meta_id==9999] as a ...) then sink eventstream no events at all. It's not what i need.

Comment: Hi, I guess it depends on how you define the last event. Since these are streams, you would need to define whether you need the last event considering, say, the last 5 min of the stream or the last N events of the stream or similar. Can you explain more with respect to what (i.e. time based, events based) you need the last event?

Comment: I need the last (in this case one) event in the stream without time conditions. Temporary stream may contain any number of events. It is important to get the latest released to the flow of the event (i need last N events of the stream).

Comment: Hi, a stream itself is a continuous flow of events and does not have a concept of last event. To get the last event you need to use a window on the stream. Consider your query of using a length window of 1. Say it would first receive event with severity 2. At this point, this is the last event and would be put to the window. When the event with severity 1 arrives, that would be the last event, and so on. Therefore you would not be able to extract a last event unless it is with respect to some sort of window that has been defined.